# How to download RTA image using url and oauth access token c#

Tags: images

Can any one help me download rta images using oauth token and url?

I am trying this in C# and appending the access token to request.

I am getting  a html page with following script -

```
<script>
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.ap1.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253D00390000019WD3X%2526feoid%253D00N9000000CBZv6%2526refid%253D0EM900000005U5H%2526oauth_token%253D00D90000000yiwM%252521AQIAQCDABP38nrJ9zXeQ9pzzbHDhKW1Zg.nsEyj60f5H61tCDLYCqYAR8PgM2QxPqUKiXmcMk5OQLYfKMTiRo3mqb2.ujSj2'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.ap1.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253D00390000019WD3X%2526feoid%253D00N9000000CBZv6%2526refid%253D0EM900000005U5H%2526oauth_token%253D00D90000000yiwM%252521AQIAQCDABP38nrJ9zXeQ9pzzbHDhKW1Zg.nsEyj60f5H61tCDLYCqYAR8PgM2QxPqUKiXmcMk5OQLYfKMTiRo3mqb2.ujSj2');
} else {;
window.location.href ='https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.ap1.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253D00390000019WD3X%2526feoid%253D00N9000000CBZv6%2526refid%253D0EM900000005U5H%2526oauth_token%253D00D90000000yiwM%252521AQIAQCDABP38nrJ9zXeQ9pzzbHDhKW1Zg.nsEyj60f5H61tCDLYCqYAR8PgM2QxPqUKiXmcMk5OQLYfKMTiRo3mqb2.ujSj2';
} 
</script>
```